# Python scrape over Webpage Loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am scraping two columns out of a table and looping the script over the HTML (there are 19 pages of tables).  However, when I enter in the range for what is supposed to be the webpage loop, it sets it as the range of rows to gain.

What am I doing wrong with my loop so that it is setting the range for the rows of data gathered INSTEAD of setting the range for the HTML pages I want to scrape over?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import csv
empty_list = []
for i in range (1,19):
    url = requests.get("https://www.foxsports.com/nhl/stats?season=2017&category=SCORING&group=1&sort=3&time=0&pos=0&team=0&qual=1&sortOrder=0&page={}".format(i))
    if not url.ok:
        continue
    data = url.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table', {'class' : 'wisbb_standardTable'})
    player = table.find('a', {'class':'wisbb_fullPlayer'}).find('span').text
    team = table.find('span',{'class':'wisbb_tableAbbrevLink'}).find('a').text
    empty_list.append((player, team))
df = pd.DataFrame(empty_list, columns=["player", "team"])
df
```

[image: sample table data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `find`, it finds the first element. You should use `find_all` instead. This gives you an array of all elements that match, then you can call `find` on each element in the array to get the data you need. You are just grabbing the first team, player pair for each of `range(1,n)` pages.

This code seems to give you what you are looking for:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
empty_list = []
for i in range (1,19):
    url = requests.get("https://www.foxsports.com/nhl/stats?season=2017&category=SCORING&group=1&sort=3&time=0&pos=0&team=0&qual=1&sortOrder=0&page={}".format(i))
    if not url.ok:
        continue
    data = url.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table', {'class' : 'wisbb_standardTable'})
    player = table.find_all('a', {'class':'wisbb_fullPlayer'})
    team = table.find_all('span',{'class':'wisbb_tableAbbrevLink'})
    player_team_data = [{"player":p.text.split('\n')[1], "team":t.text.strip('\n')} for p,t in zip(player,team)]
    for p in player_team_data:
        empty_list.append(p)
df = pd.DataFrame(empty_list, columns=["player", "team"])

df.shape

(900, 2)
```

Comment: sorry I just updated the code again. I tested it and was able to scrape all 900 players. does that work for you?